# export a datatable into multiple sheets excel

Tags: javascript, datatables-1.10

On a php webpage, I'm looking for a solution to export many Datatables in one Excel file with different sheets. One datatable = One sheet.

I found a code for two datatables here : http://live.datatables.net/qinoxinu/6/edit
It works great but I can't adapt the code for 3 datatables and more. I am stuck.. 
Here is a example with 3 datatables but it doesn't work, the third table is the second table.  http://live.datatables.net/kuyayeto/1/edit

The different between the two codes are the addSheet function. 'sheet2' is replaced by 'sheet' + sheetId. The sheet creation/title of the new sheet work but not the content of the table. The element of the third table is not tooken in count.

Can someone help me ?